# get key from translated value in ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I use @ngx-translate and localize-router.
Can't resolve the valid slug from a localized URL
if the translate of 'about' is 'asd' then

```
   routerLink="about/{{'about' | localize}}" //href="about/asd"
```

but if in the route I have

```
   {path: ':slug', component...}
```

and if I get by a slug from activatedRoute in component
the slug asd does not exist

I managed because I have all the translation in the database too so if it doesn't find a record with that slug, it iterates from all translation and when it finds the translated value it returns the key and searches for the new slug

Is there a way to get the key from the translated string in the translationService like get or instant method?

Comment: Before you resolve your problem I have a suggestion for you (I know this is not your question) but I strongly recommend to *not use* `localize-router` library at all. It has a lot of bugs and it never got a stable version. If you want to use lazy module or more complicate structure in your project this library is not for you. Much better for you is to create own component to keep a languages detection.

Comment: Thanks, I already got and avoid some of those bugs, if you know another library that can do it and it's more stable, let me know because I need those behaviors.

Comment: if you solve this problem in library update you can remove this post from stack

Comment: I avoid, I did not solve it, but if I got no answer probably there is no way to do it, so I will try to pull request on Github

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - I add this comment during other work and I wasn't careful enough... I add one answer - maybe it will be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I used `localize-router` in few projects, and I had similar problems in each of them. But - what is really misleading - sometimes I get different behaviour when I use: 
`[routerLink]=""` 
over 
`routerLink=""`.

You can try also this option:

```
        this.activatedRoute.root.url
            .subscribe(res => {
                const params = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
            });
```

or this (it's not exactly what you need but sometimes can help):

```
        this.activatedRoute.root.url
            .subscribe(res => {
                const wholeUrl  = this.router.url;
            });
```

It's also another service for snapshot: `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` but it doesn't work in my last project with Jasmine Unit tests - it's a problem with mock this.